# Can I use a Cat 5e cable (inside walls), a Cat6 insert in the wall and a cat 6 cable to connect to the computer?

Tags: networking, ethernet, cable, cat6, cat5e

I only have cat6 wall insert but I'm not sure if the cat5e cable inside the wall will be compatible with it. I'd rather not have to replace the cable inside the wall.

Comment: You will only get cat5e speeds

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're trying to run 10GBaseT then there's no functional difference between Cat5/5e/6/6a/7/etc.  You can safely terminate a cat5e cable on a cat6-rated jack and then plug in a cat5 patch cable (or any combination therein) without a problem as long as you're running at 1G or less.